# Is there any conditional formatting option to highlight the cell colors for the same cell values (not numeric)?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Consider:

[image]

I want to highlight the cell color of the same values in my Excel sheet with the conditional formatting. Is it possible to colorize the same values (for example, https://www.google.com/ should be in red, and other is different colors) from the image.

I have tried conditional formatting.

Comment: Use `$A1="https://www.google.com/"` and apply `A:A`. Then for other values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula to find the index of a string in a list, and you can use conditional formatting (colour scale) on that list:

```
=MATCH(A1;UNIQUE(A$1:A$8);0)
```

It's not a final solution, but it's a start. Here's a screenshot of an example:

[image]